# Why is d3 exit() length higher than expected?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've appended two 'p' tags to the body of a dummy page like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.4/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I run the following command to bind an array of one number to the first 'p' tag and return D3's exit selection for all 'p' tags:

```
d3.selectAll('p').data([1]).exit();
```

d3 then returns the following (copied from the Chrome Dev Tools console):

```
[ Array[2]             
1: p
length: 2
parentNode: html
__proto__: Array[0]
]
```

I don't see a 0th element in this array, but I do see a 1st element (the 'p' tag with no data bound to it).  d3 is telling me the length of this array is 2, so what is the 0th element and why is it not displayed here?

Tangent question- my understanding of the exit() function is that it returns the elements from the selection that were not bound to any data.  So why is the length of this array 2 (which sounds like it represents both the bound and unbound 'p' tags) instead of 1 (just the 'p' tag with no data bound to it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exit selection is derived from the entire selection, which in your case contains two elements. The important bit here is *selection* -- it's not an array. In many ways, it behaves similar to an array and you can do many things with it you can also do with an array, but these functions rely on custom implementations to work with selections.

So basically the output you're getting from the debugger is a bit misleading here. It's an object that has some of the properties of an array (and this is what Chrome uses to display it), but it's not really an array.

What matters in the end is that the right elements end up in the right place, and as you have observed, this is the case.